How to use SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID on paired files with a for loop?
I have a folder with 180 files that are paired as *R1.fastq.gz and *R2.fastq.gz in their names. So it could be "abc_R1.fastq.gz" and "abc_R2.fastq.gz" as one pair and there are 90 of these pairs.
I have a program called spades that runs the following on a R1 and R2 pair.
bin/spades.py --meta -1 abc_R1.fastq.gz -2 abc_R2.fastq.gz -o output_folder

I have a folder called "fastq" with 90 pairs that read like so:
abc_R1.fastq.gz
abc_R2.fastq.gz
zxy_R1.fastq.gz
zxy_R2.fastq.gz
dfg_R1.fastq.gz
...

I would like to use SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID on each pair in a for loop and have the output be the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID name with the contents inside. So something like this:
file1=$(ls /filepath/*R1.fastq.gz | sed -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p)
file2=$(ls /filepath/*R2.fastq.gz | sed -n ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p)

spades.py --meta -1 ${file1} -2 ${file2} -o outputpath/"${file1##R1.fast.gz}p"

As noted: SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is basically the line number of the ls output for file names 1 and 2 where the first two file names would be "1" for SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID. This allows parallelization on a cluster.
How could I do this in a loop? The problem I'm having is the above can work but only on an array of 25 files. The server cannot do an array of 90. Which is why a for loop would be better for my case. The output name is not that important but I would like it to be associated with the file name pair.
Any help would be appreciated!!!

assuming SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID is an integer then "${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}p" is going to create a file named <integer>p which I assume is not what you're intending soooo, what do you really want the output file to be named?

Sorry, SLURM TASK ID is commonly used in HPC clustering so i didnt think I needed to specify. The output can be anything, it could actually just be ${file1} . Just as long as I can tie it back to the original pair.

probably an ok assumption for people coming to this question based on the bioinformatics and/or slurm tags, but for people coming here based on the bash and for-loop tags (like me) the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID reference is greek

yeah totally understandable. My issue also is that I myself do not fully understand it. But yes in this case I guess I am making SLURM ARRAY TASK ID the line number from the 'ls' output of filenames. So 1-90 for file1 and file 2 names.

starting over from scratch: for input file1=abc-R1.fastq.gz and an output file named abc-OUT.fastq.gz you could change "${file1##R1.fast.gz}p" to "${file1/R1/OUT}"

please update the question with more details on what you mean by kind of works but only for a given array size; what 'size' is ok and what 'size' is not ok? what happens when 'size' is too big?

So theoretically you do an array of 90 to do all files. But the server can only do 25 at a time. If you do 25 it will just loop over first 25 files ( I think) and not the whole 90

that appears to change the whole purpose of your question or perhaps that should be a completely new/different question: an issue with slurm configuration when looping over a large number of files such that slurm appears to repeatedly process the first 25 files; that's a completely different issue than (effectively) 'how to name the output file'

My title literally says how to use SLURM TASK ID in a for loop

It's unclear if SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID, SLURM_TASK_ID and "SLURM TASK ID" are separate identifiers/text OR if they are shorthand for each other. Please add code at the top that sets values for all variable names you expect to use. Might help to read about [mcve] and reflect on how your question still needs some vital information. You may also find that the  section How to turn a bad script into a good question will help you solve your problem and/or improve your question (I haven't downvoted, yet (-;! )  Good luck.

I think its pretty fair to assume that for someone to give me the proper answer they would have to know what slurm task ID refers to. But I updated it to make it more clear.
I swear people spend more time on here critiquing people's questions instead of providing guidance on the actual solution

Assuming you want to keep one instance of spades.py per job, you can organise the work like this:
Submission script submit.sh:
#/bin/bash
#SBATCH ...
#SBATCH --array=0-17

OFFSET=${1:-0}
IDX=$((OFFSET*18+SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID))

file1=$(ls /filepath/*R1.fastq.gz | sed -n ${IDX}p)
file2=$(ls /filepath/*R2.fastq.gz | sed -n ${IDX}p)

spades.py --meta -1 ${file1} -2 ${file2} -o outputpath/"${file1##R1.fast.gz}"

And then, submit it in the following loop:
for i in {0..4}; do sbatch submit.sh $i ; done

This is untested so you will have to check all indices and bounds. The aim is to submit five  18-tasks job array to process the 90 pairs of files. You can test by adding an echo in front of the spades.py line as suggested by @markp-fuso, and replacing sbatch with bash in the for-looop.

ok will try this. What is the point of offsetting and the IDX equation? My guess is it forces the next job to start at 18 and so and on but having trouble seeing the math behind it.

Yes because the SLURM_TASK_ARRAY_ID cannot have a value bigger than the MaxArraySize, which I understand is set at 25 on your cluster.
